# IR Remote POWER event when using EVDEV library

Tags: python, power

I have a python script that handles IR remote events using the EVDEV library.

The problem I have is that the when debugging the KEY_POWER event code, it completely powers down the PI.

Ideally, I want to intercept this event and manage any saving of config settings in my app before powering down.

Is there any way to prevent the default behaviour and ensure EVDEV manages the event instead?